# gcc not autovectorising matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, simd, auto-vectorization

I have just begun playing around with my vectorising code. My matrix-vector multiplication code is not being autovectorised by `gcc`, I’d like to know why. [This pastebin contains the output from](https://pastebin.com/uVy5JuJZ) `-fopt-info-vec-missed`.

I’m having trouble understanding what the output is telling me and seeing how it matches up to what I’ve written in code.

For instance, I see a number of lines saying `not enough data-refs in basic block`, I can’t find much detail online with a google search about this. I also see that there’s issues relating to memory alignment e.g. `Unknown misalignment, naturally aligned` and `vector alignment may not be reachable`. All of my memory allocation was for `double` types using `malloc`, which I believed was guaranteed to be aligned for that type.

Environment: compiling with `gcc` on WSL2

```
gcc -v: gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 4000 // Matrix size will be N x N
#define T 1

//gcc -fopenmp -g vectorisation.c -o main -O3 -march=native -fopt-info-vec-missed=missed.txt

void doParallelComputation(double *A, double *V, double *results, unsigned long matrixSize, int numThreads)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(numThreads);
    unsigned long i, j;

    #pragma omp parallel for simd private(j)
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
    {
        // double *AHead = &A[i * matrixSize];
        // double tmp = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
        {
            results[i] += A[i * matrixSize + j] * V[j];
            // also tried tmp += A[i * matrixSize + j] * V[j];
        }
        // results[i] = tmp;
    }

}

void genRandVector(double *S, unsigned long size)
{
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned long i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        double n = rand() % 5;
        S[i] = n;
    }
}

void genRandMatrix(double *A, unsigned long size)
{
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned long i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                double n = rand() % 5;
                A[i*size + j] = n;
            }

        }
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double *V = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));     // v in our A*v = parV computation
    double *parV = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));  // Parallel computed vector
    double *A = (double *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(double)); // NxN Matrix to multiply by V
    genRandVector(V, N);
    doParallelComputation(A, V, parV, N, T);

    free(parV);
    free(A);
    free(V);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, GCC's auto-vectorizer would be happier if it knew both matrix and vector were aligned by 32 or 64, e.g. from C11 `aligned_alloc`.  After inlining, it can probably see that directly without further hints like `__builtin_assume_aligned`

Comment: Without `-ffast-math`, I think you need to tell OpenMP about reductions specifically, to let it relax FP-math associativity.  That might be why it's not auto-vectorizing the row dot-product that sums `A[i * matrixSize + j] * V[j];`.  Hmm, no, seems that's not it either.  With `-ffast-math` and with OpenMP commented out (https://godbolt.org/z/qxhGon), still no auto-vec of that.  Ah, but adding `double *restrict results` did the trick, to promise non-overlapping input/output.  https://godbolt.org/z/qaPh1v

Comment: A further question regarding the godbolt links. I posted below that i'm seeing speedup from the accepted answer, but when I look in godbolt [it says that it couldn't vectorise the loop](https://i.imgur.com/5VUIAqH.png). My ability to read and parse assembly isn't great (working on it as I learn parallel computing), but [I don't see any vector function calls in the generated assembly either](https://i.imgur.com/5VUIAqH.png). Where in the assembly does it jump to a block using vector calls? I see there's vector functions in `.L6` in one of the links, but I can't see how it gets there.

Comment: `doParallelComputation` calls `GOMP_parallel`, passing a pointer to `doParallelComputation._omp_fn.0`.  That function contains `vfmadd231pd` (pd = packed double, vs. sd = scalar double).  And it's using a YMM register, 32-bytes.  There aren't any "vector function calls", only SIMD FP math *instructions* inside the inner loop.  If you'd called `exp()` or something then GCC might have vectorized that by calling a SIMD library function, but FMA inlines directly.  Re: GCC loop reports: the outer loop isn't vectorized, only parallelized.  But GCC noisily talks about everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adding `double *restrict results` to promise non-overlapping input/output helped, *without* OpenMP but with `-ffast-math`.  https://godbolt.org/z/qaPh1v**

You need to tell OpenMP about reductions specifically, to let it relax FP-math associativity.  (`-ffast-math` doesn't help the OpenMP vectorizer).   With that as well, we get what you want:
**`#pragma omp simd reduction(+:tmp)`**

---

With just `restrict` and no `-ffast-math` or `-fopenmp`, you get total garbage: it does a SIMD FP multiply, but then unpacks that for 4x `vaddsd` into the scalar accumulator, not helping hide FP latency at all.

**With `restrict` and `-fopenmp` (without fast-math), it just does scalar FMA.**

With `restrict` and `-ffast-math` (**without `-fopenmp`** or `#pragma` commented) it auto-vectorizes nicely: `vfmadd231pd ymm` inside the loop, shuffle / add horizontal sum outside. (But doesn't parallelize).   https://godbolt.org/z/f36oG3

With `restrict` and `-ffast-math` (**with** `-fopenmp`) it still doesn't auto-vectorize.  The OpenMP vectorizer is different, and maybe doesn't take advantage of fast-math, instead needing you to tell it about reductions?

---

**Also note that with your data layout, the loop you want to parallelize (outer) is different from the loop you want to vectorize with SIMD (inner).**  Both the input "vectors" for the inner dot-product loop are in contiguous memory so it makes the most sense to read those, instead of trying to SIMD shuffle data from 4 different columns into one vector to accumulate 4 `result[i+0..3]` results in 1 vector.

However, unrolling the outer loop by 4 to use each `V[j+0..3]` with data from 4 different columns would improve computational intensity (closer to 1 load per FMA, rather than 2)

(As long as `V[]` *and* a row of the matrix fits in L1d cache, this is good.  If not, it's actually pretty bad and should get cache-blocked.  Or actually if you unroll the outer loop, 4 rows of the matrix.)

---

Also note that `double tmp = 0;` would be a good idea: your current version adds into `result[i]`, reading it before writing.  That would require zero-init before you could use it as a pure output.

### Auto-vec auto-par version:

I think this is correct; the asm looks like it auto-parallelized as well as auto-vectorizing the inner loop.

```
void doParallelComputation(double *restrict A, double *restrict V, double *restrict results, unsigned long matrixSize, int numThreads)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(numThreads);
    unsigned long i, j;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(j)
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
    {
        // double *AHead = &A[i * matrixSize];
        double tmp = 0;

         // TODO: unroll outer loop and cache-block it.
        #pragma omp simd reduction(+:tmp)
        for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
        {
            //results[i] += A[i * matrixSize + j] * V[j];
            tmp += A[i * matrixSize + j] * V[j];  // 
        }
        results[i] = tmp;  // write-only to results, not adding to old value.
    }

}
```

Compiles ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BIyeMQzDAAqW78p4obEsokw0MQkwgXgQqopgEB8Eu66bghkwQHgBzapM6z/t%2BBw6PKqLosOo6YKReByHIWFPpu4iroBz6bgieYJkmyabAAEue/oOtMkgAGzbAArNIBHJpRQ4jni4hSdq/4cZxPHVgQ/KiSRD5eppG7AaB4HMJBnjYngRj%2Bmm6AGMkdAQHIIA6Z4zFGfBJB4XwhHEaRvm3Ap1FKXRD6TH%2BMhMRpnFsY%2BnnPgiTYtgoKmySpRGMTq2ZpXJwWYqFYnSBFGUppMZZpX%2BqnqdhCWTG5RWidJsllYOIW0UVJWqWVFUyVVanhfCiIxUBy5qbVnHJa2uWlaJbmkUNkz4uiBCYLKtCsAAnvVcpTW2ky0KgDbzvgX5EFurD%2BqhhhLDFbHjUC2xjV6Pp%2BpMwBaAASiI6BlqKJBxvmfEMO2nZ4N2Lofv2Vl4sxcUxQooHaBA8zoesnT3vFm6vuD76foKDEGW8E24fhfn6cVBFBbiYWU4xMgeax7ETc%2BVZJrQflI%2BgECdGJUmTFJNUsZpDAzd1om0ELo0PfdL2%2Bv6H20N92gokOgO8YWOYvmDEO9tDNNw8zwvYlzKPWWjGNS9jOt49DP4lUTxvPqTVPZRTZHU7R9H09IjOafDLNGaTgVuwF5Ew7TJVRQzI1GQHTt1Vp7Ocz9PN8wLVuJ5uzV4MmNOdf1fmS47Wey8TCfGc9E1l49E6UdY%2BH0JM6RsrmyAIOkKYt0KaUZYbAETWzhZln56vVsmnQKsSqDIBAkLyTTqBUGP7CW4NXGIkK34c70iGbMmW%2BidBxAj2gUYxv4MVDymx8j6JK%2BFpPYYz3PZWL8vQ9r8Vi0hqBsEkmfTw0ZIYWjFFfIGmtR7XwnlPPss957kgXrRJeD8v6LVsBiSEqtqI7XlM2NQngtqkm2hVCaitla/X%2BsQCAFYISY3Ab/MMyhIxAIvk5LWtDb65lsLmOk9Dy7OzTOhW%2B/DjZUCERATYojBGYHQmWaRrEJppgIH0DmFMVzakGN0VgIBBhSUGKQUwgx1gGNQLonQPtsS7wGGJNwnADEEF0SYjGpAADWIBuAAA5FgAE4YTuCkuJcSbhlyeOCR4HRgxuAGKMSY0gZjBgGIUCAdYpBHHGK0aQOAsAYCIBQNuIkzhyCUEAYUlwwBlxSVIGCFszhkkQAcE4gxDhrDpE2ro%2BxpAz4LHoMqDa7SMmkCwAqUQ7AmlDLwGmZIIpkmDMwBiJIwCOkGInMocZDwHCgWIJtPQWBllpPREYZZ3QaD0CYGwDgPB%2BCuCECIMQPshCPGSZAboqBPAFFmZyDEMpVSGjeXySyVp0jtwdAoVxm1hCuP2NyN5xpTSoHNEkK0No7RJMSI5UwEBzB1ByKQcwpRoixBuaEPwdAcUhB8KS2gBLyhxDyKKFITRyUNHRQUIoGQaVtBcA0Jl%2BhsiCEaMUTlRLODdAUNYy52jdH6MMeMhJGIwmcnEtwd67JJjLkWPzCAuBCDeRGLkSYLCym2K6Ian2DimkuIQMJCoPM3EgCkpwRY6wfE%2BOXMqtwbhxKSE4F65cvBInRNIEc5cTrPEdHWJ6zxPjPFuHWFJdYnjZWDISUklJaTLVZNyRAJAvQCCsOKRAUp7A6Uul1dy6pdBGAsDGVc5azBPDHKENKmJcrdEjEkEtQgCAKSKuVaqjkGqZXpOcd0a185bVSqiQYo5khvGcGXMuHxQTODrE4OJHx3AfELuTXE1Nih00jq0d0dxjrnWuvddwT13rfXiX9c2wYbhW0pt0RajJLjImSGfXu19Gb33dBFMQXwGhuBAA%3D%3D%3D)) with a vectorized inner loop inside the OpenMPified helper function `doParallelComputation._omp_fn.0:`

```
# gcc7.5 -xc -O3 -fopenmp -march=skylake
.L6:
        add     rdx, 1               # loop counter; newer GCC just compares the end-pointer
        vmovupd ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax]            # 32-byte load
        vfmadd231pd     ymm0, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]  # 32-byte memory-source FMA
        add     rax, 32                                # pointer increment
        cmp     rdi, rdx
        ja      .L6
```

Then a horizontal sum of mediocre efficiency after the loop; unfortunately the OpenMP vectorizer isn't as smart as the "normal" `-ftree-vectorize` vectorizer, but that requires `-ffast-math` to do anything here.

Comment: Very informative answer. I am seeing some pretty respectable speedup when using this in conjunction with OpenMP as problem size grows. [See here](https://i.imgur.com/R8bOhmm.png). I plan on implementing loop tiling in the next couple of days. Regarding loop unrolling: i've tried unrolling it by adding 4 iterations in one pass, but there’s a slight performance hit. [See here](https://i.imgur.com/L2DX4q5.png). What are the important considerations for loop unrolling?

Comment: @daviegravee: important for unrolling: cache-block it first, with that 4k x 4k size.  4k * 8 bytes per double = 32kiB memory footprint, the size of L1d cache.  You can try unrolling with smaller matrix dimensions, so e.g. the vector *and* 4 whole rows of the matrix fit in L1d cache.

Comment: Can I confirm that this is the general technique for cache-blocking. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/6EjbYc). I'm going to revisit this tomorrow. I am getting better speedup, and it appears to be vectorised, but i'm going to have to think a little bit more carefully about how to unroll these loops appropriately.

Comment: @daviegravee: don't use `fmin` for integer min; that hides a lot of information from the compiler and is slower than a normal `x<y ? x : y`.  That may be what defeated auto-vectorization, or just that you removed `#pragma omp simd reduction` from the inner loop.  A power-of-2 block size would be normal, especially a multiple of the cache-line size.  8 floats fit in a 64-byte cache line, and 20 isn't a multiple of 8.  But yes I think you have the right idea as far as cache-blocking in general.  (But it's a lot of logic to actually verify that it all makes sense.)

Comment: @daviegravee: related: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126311) has a cache-blocked matrix multiply example (with manual vectorization).  Auto-vectorization may be all you need, especially for matrix-vector, or at least good enough.

Comment: Sorry the code example was meant to highlight the tiling, not the actual block size I would use. I'm taking a break on this for a few hours (read: sleep). Really appreciative of the help, i've learned a lot today!

Comment: @daviegravee: Yeah, I understood the main point, I was just pointing out the things I was able to notice without putting in a lot of effort to fully verify you had the logic right.  An extra two levels of loop nesting is the right idea, though.